# Integration of product of lower incomplete gamma function with exponential function.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, gamma-function

How to solve the following definite integral:

$$\int\limits_0^\infty  {\gamma \left( {N,\frac{c}{{ax + b}}} \right){e^{ - x}}dx} $$?

$a, b, c \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a,b,c>0$ This is indeed similar to the CDF for the product of a gamma-distributed variable and an exponential-distributed variable, but they are different due to $b$. I can't find the closed-form solution or approximate solution of the above definite integral.

Comment: *Welcome to the site !*. Could you tell what you tried and explain where you are stuck ?

Comment: I can't find the closed-form solution or approximate solution of the above definite integral.

Comment: Kenn Tie, if you show us what have you tried and where you are stuck then we can help you exactly at that point where you got stuck.